# Caramel sauce tastes too sugary what went wrong

Tags: sauce, caramel

I tried a recipe to create caramel sauce, where the instructions were basically slowly heat sugar to 350F / 176c then take off heat, add cream, put back on heat, then mix and it's ready.

When finished the sauce looked like caramel and had the right texture but tasted sugary instead of having that caramel flavour.

Is it that it was undercooked or it's just that a caramel sugar and cream recipe always tastes sugary and I should add something else to get that distinctive flavour?

Comment: What color was the resulting caramel?

Answer (score 2):

By 'cream,' I am assuming you mean heavy whipping cream, which is normally used in caramel sauce, and *not* sweetened condensed cream, which some people use in place of sweetened condensed milk in certain recipes.
 The whipping cream in itself, is not sweet, so I'm not sure what the issue could be. Did you accidentally put too much sugar in? Or maybe next time try replacing the cream with butter, or try adding just a pinch of salt to the mixture to combat the sweetness.

Comment: I used a pure cream, I tried later with butter and it got closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like the sugar caramelized. When you start off cooking sugar, it will taste sugary, and it will stay that way unless you cook it long enough. It needs to become more of a golden brown color, at which point the taste evolves from sugary to a caramel taste.

Here is an article on methods to caramelize sugar: http://www.wikihow.com/Caramelize-Sugar